# Laravel 5 Image upload

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I use Laravel 5.1 and want to upload a image within my form:

blade:

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ url('upload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="picture" type="file" class="uploader" id="picture" value="Upload" />
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
 </form>
```

My route:

```
 Route::post('upload', 'MyController@upload');
```

My controller:

```
 public function upload(Request $request){
     if ($request->hasFile('picture'){}
 }
```

The problem is that the if statement always return false. Any ideas why? Thank you

Comment: You've to set the `'files' => true` in the form.

Comment: My form is simply :  <form method="POST" action="{{ url('upload') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data"> Where I have to set 'files' => true ? Thank you

Comment: @JilsonThomas This code is just fine, there's no Form Builder code to set files to true, which would just add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` that is already there.

Comment: @Bogdan: yeah just saw it now.

Comment: @Steve I've just tried this code, and it works just fine. There must be something else at play there. BTW how are you submitting that form, because there's no submit button? Are you doing some XHR request?

Comment: I edited the post and added the submit button I use

Comment: @Steve That code is still valid and should work. Please post your route definition and entire controller action method.

Comment: I updated my post. When I use   dd($request->file('picture')); in my controller upload method it returns null

Comment: code seems working from my end too.

Comment: Is it necessary to add some configuration somewhere in laravel regarding the uploaded image types or the image size?

Comment: Try using:
 dd($request->all());

It may show you what's going on.

Comment: Maybe you're trying to upload a file that is too large. How large is the file and if you add this `dump(ini_get('post_max_size')); dump(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));` to your controller method, what is the output?

Comment: If any of the sizes outputted by the two statements are less than the size of the file you're trying to upload, then that is a reason for `hasFile` to returns `false`, although I think `dd($request->file('picture'))`  should still dump an `UploadeFile` object, just one with `size: 0` and `error: 1`.

Comment: Where I can raise the image size?

Comment: Those configuration values are set in `php.ini`. Read [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/) for more help on that.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: remove this attribute `value="Upload"` from input type file